# Как проверить пустой ли ответ запроса к mysql2?

Tags: mysql, typescript

Я использую `mysql2/promise` для получения выборки из базы данных. Если запрос дал результат и нашел записи в базе, то все хорошо, я получаю записи, но если запрос не дал результата, как это проверить? Казалось бы, все просто, будь это обычный массив, я бы просто проверил lenght и определил бы есть ли результат. Но как в данном случае понять, что ответ базы данных пустой?
В моем случае `if (tasks)` всегда срабатывает, получил ли я записи из базы данных или же нет.

```ts
import {Result} from "../Result";
import {Errors} from "../Error";
import {userAuthorised} from "../userAuthorised";
import { Connection, RowDataPacket } from "mysql2/promise";

export const getTasks = async (result: Result, db: Connection, body: any) => {
    try {
        await userAuthorised(db, body)
        try {
            const [tasks] = await db.query(`select * from tasks where project_id = ${body.project_id} and parent_id ${body.task_id === undefined ?  'is null' : '= ' + body.task_id}`)
            if (tasks) result.tasks = tasks
            else result.error = Errors.tasksNotFound()
        } catch (error) {
            result.error = Errors.dbError()
        }
    } catch (error) {
        result.error = error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо сначала проверить, что ответ является массивом, и уже тогда становится доступен параметр `lenght`

```ts
if (Array.isArray(tasks) && tasks.length > 0) result.tasks = tasks
```

Если же сразу написать так:

```ts
if (tasks.length > 0) result.tasks = tasks
```

Тогда будет ошибка.

Еще можно так

```ts
const tasks = res as RowDataPacket[]
if (tasks.length > 0) result.tasks = tasks
```